# Deleting points outside polygon with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

How can I delete all points (rows) in one table that fall outside a polygon stored in a different table? Assume the tables follow the common convention of storing the geometry in a column named `geom`.

Comment: By 'lines' do you mean database records/features, because you only mention point and polygon geometry?  Have you tried ST_Intersection?

Comment: Yes, it is the number of records/features...

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `SELECT` subquery in a `DELETE` query.  So your query would look something like:

```
DELETE FROM points_table WHERE 
points_table.id IN (
    SELECT a.id FROM
      points_table a, polygon_table b
      WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
 );
```

`id` is the primary key, or some other column with a unique constraint in your points table.

Alternatively, you can use `ST_Disjoint` to find points that do not intersect the polygon, but PostGIS cannot make use of spatial indexes to determine whether geometries are disjoint. `NOT ST_Intersects` will be more efficient.

Second Edit:  If your polygon layer contains more than one feature you'll need to union them together. Otherwise the above query will delete all your points, as each point will fall outside *some* polygon (unless you're dealing with an unusual dataset with overlapping polygons). That changes the query to this:

```
DELETE FROM points_table WHERE 
points_table.id IN (
    SELECT a.id FROM
      points_table a, (
           SELECT ST_Union(geom) As geom FROM polygon_table
      ) b
      WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
 );
```